# Cannot add Youtube videos using ckeditor

Tags: php, youtube, ckeditor

Im using CkEditor in a blog website, the problem is when I add a youtube video to the editor and wants to save the post it gives me this error:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /blog/newpost.php on this
>   server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

***N.B: it works fine in localhost with xampp.***

Here is the code

```
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>  

        // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
        // instance, using default configuration.
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
            magicline_color: 'blue',
            // Load the German interface.
            language: 'fr',
            uiColor: '#4caf50',            
        });        
    </script>
```

**config.js**

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
// Define changes to default configuration here.
// For complete reference see:
// http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

// The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'others' },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'about' },
    { name: 'insert', groups: ['Image', 'Youtube']}
];


    // Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
    // not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
    config.removeButtons             = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Set the most common block elements.
    config.format_tags               = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

    // Simplify the dialog windows.
    config.removeDialogTabs          = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
    config.extraPlugins              = 'youtube';
};
```

**N.B: The problem occurs only when I add a youtube video**

Comment: you flaged php youtue ckeditor and the error message is from **apache** or equal webserver ... so check configuration, pathes etc

Comment: Which configuration do you mean?

Comment: It depends on what webserver you use. Also - you can check logs of your framemork/CMS. You will find there perhaps why access is forbidden. For instance, if you use Apache you may have mod_secure enabled and AFAIK it may block requests with weird markup.